# How can i get money value from a string value in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, format, currency

I have a String values in sql and i need to make it small and get it as money if possible.

```
String value1 is : 104811140,00
String value2 is : 11229775,62

What i need to get is: 
1: 104.811.140,00
2: 11.229.775,62
 or
1: 104.811
2: 11.229

both are ok..
```

How can i do this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the idea behind 104811140,00  becoming 104.811

Comment: can't you just cast as money? or use convert function to cast it?

Comment: @TheGameiswar the idea is i cannot report that value in SSRS. it shows like 57,355,383 in N0 format but I need to see it as 573,55

Comment: @FLICKER i tried but i couldnt get it with just 1 comma like 104,81 or 11,229 . when i cast it as money, it shows  the same (104811140,00) but i need to reduce it as 104.811

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
option1 = convert(varchar(20), convert(money, str), 1),
option2 = convert(varchar(20), floor(convert(money, str) / 1000), 1)
```

Comment: it did not work :( i solved it using isnull and float. thanks.

Comment: what does the query gives you ? In what way it doesn't work ?